# Spring IoC and Generic Interface Type

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, types, generics

I'm trying to use Spring IoC with an interface like this:

```
public interface ISimpleService<T> {
    void someOp(T t);
    T otherOp();
}
```

Can Spring provide IoC based on the generic type argument T? I mean, something like this:

```
public class SpringIocTest {
    @Autowired
    ISimpleService<Long> longSvc;

    @Autowired
    ISimpleService<String> strSvc;
    //...
}
```

Of course, my example above does not work:

```
expected single matching bean but found 2: [serviceLong, serviceString]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInstantiation(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:243)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:957)
```

My Question: is it possible to provide a similar functionality with minimum modifications to either the Interface or the implementing classes? I know for instance I can use @Qualifiers, but I want to keep things as simple as possible.

Comment: It seems to be possible now since Spring 4.0. See this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22603321/196533) and the Spring article titled [Spring Framework 4.0 and Java Generics](http://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-and-java-generics).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I do not believe this is possible due to erasure. We generally switched to strongly typed sub-interfaces  when going for full-autowiring:

```
public interface LongService extends ISimpleService<Long> {}
public interface StringService extends ISimpleService<String> {}
```

Upon doing this switch we found we actually liked this pretty well, because it allows us to do "find usage" tracking much better, something you loose with the generics interfaces.

Comment: And how do you deal with code duplication? Probably have a middle class that is also generic, no? Tks

Comment: The only duplication necessary is the marker interface. But you're not showing your implementation classes so I can't tell if you're doing anything I'm not seeing!

Comment: The implementation would suit another SO question :)

Answer (score 14):

i don't think thats possible without Qualifier

ill try to show my Solutions with a genericDAO, sorry if it's a bit detailed

the Interface and Implementation Class Definition

```
public interface GenericDAO<T, ID extends Serializable> (...)

public class GenericDAOImpl<T, ID extends Serializable>
    implements GenericDAO<T, ID> 
    (...) important is this constructor
    public GenericDAOImpl(Class<T> persistentClass) {
       this.persistentClass = persistentClass;
    }
```

the spring bean definition, notice the abstract="true"

```
<bean id="genericHibernateDAO" class="de.optimum24.av.pers.ext.hibernate.dao.GenericDAOImpl"
      abstract="true">
    <description>
        <![CDATA[
            Definition des GenericDAO.
        ]]>
    </description>
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

**Using this genericDAO without special implementation Class**

```
 <bean id="testHibernateChildDao" class="de.optimum24.av.pers.ext.hibernate.dao.GenericDAOImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>de.optimum24.av.pers.test.hibernate.domain.TOChild</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

notice the constructor-arg with an concrete Class, if you work with Spring Annotation you need to do:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier(value = "testHibernateChildDao")
private GenericDAO<TOChild, Integer> ToChildDAO;
```

to distinguish the various versions of genericDao Beans (notice the Qualifier with direct Reference to the Beanname)

**Using this genericDAO with special implementation Class**

the Interface and Class

```
public interface TestHibernateParentDAO extends GenericDAO<TOParent, Integer>{
  void foo();
}
public class TestHibernateParentDAOImpl extends GenericDAOImpl<TOParent, Integer>
                              implements TestHibernateParentDAO {
  @Override
  public void foo() {
      //* no-op */
  }
}
```

the Bean Definition, notice the "parent" Reference to the abstract genericDAO above

```
<bean id="testHibernateParentDao" class="de.optimum24.av.pers.test.hibernate.dao.TestHibernateParentDAOImpl"
      parent="genericHibernateDAO" />
```

and usage with Spring Annotation

```
@Autowired
private TestHibernateParentDAO ToParentDAO;
```

Comment: Great answer hitting on both the Annotation and XML usages. Did this solution work out for you in the long term? Where there any drawbacks to using this methodology like being able to trace through code easier (mentioned by Krosenvold in 1st post)?

Comment: it is more of a organizational/knowledge problem, if the developers know the process it does work, this generic method is certainly harder to handle than the use of (marker) interfaces

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to do this with erasure, if the generic type is fully reified at compile-time. In this case the type information is available via either of:

```
Class#getGenericInterfaces()
Class#getGenericSuperclass()
```

This is the major feature of Guice which is missing from Spring.

Answer (score 3):

Don't make your interface generic. Make your methods, instead:

```
public interface ISimpleService {
    public <T> T doSomething(T param);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

When doing this with certain persistence layers, [Spring Data](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data) does this for you. Spring Data is a really great time-saving and simplification tool if you are using JPA, or Neo4j, or MongoDB, or something else that it supports.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to annotate the interface implementing bean with name on one side and to annotate with qualifier pointing to created name on the other side :) Here is a quick example I am using in my project :

```
 public interface IDAO<T> {

         public void insert(T model);
         public void update(T model);
         public void delete(T model);
  }
```

Abstract class as predecessor :

```
public abstract class AbstractHibernateDAO {

         protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

         protected Session currentSession() {
             return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
         }
    }
```

Implementation of abstract class for entity user:

```
@Repository(value = "userRepository") 
public class UserDAO extends AbstractHibernateDAO implements IDAO<User> {

    @Autowired
    public UserDAO(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void insert(User user) {
        currentSession().save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(User user) {
        currentSession().update(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(User user) {
        currentSession().delete(user);
    }
```

}

And finally injecting right implementation:

```
@Resource
@Qualifier(value = "userRepository")
IDAO<User> userPersistence;
```