# Inject anonymous classes with spring

Tags: java, spring, instantiation, anonymous-class

I've read a lot about [getting generic type at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3403909/518204) and I've understood that to prevent full type erasure and get generic type without giving it to constructor I can use an anonymous class plus an utility method, i.e.

```
interface Generic<T> {
    public Class<T> getGenericType();
}

@Component
class GenericImpl<T> extends AbstractGenericImpl<T> {

}

abstract class AbstractGenericImpl<T> implements Generic<T> {

    protected Class<T> klass;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Class<T> getGenericType() {
        if (klass == null) {
            // this is a spring utility method
            klass = (Class<T>) GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArgument(getClass(), AbstractGenericImpl.class);
        }
        return klass;
    }
}
```

Now using the previous class hierarchy I can have a working `getGenericType` method if and only if I instantiate a `Generic<Anything>` using an anonymous class. In fact in this test only the first two assertions are working:

```
@Test
public void testGeneric() throws Exception {
    Generic<String> anonymous = new AbstractGenericImpl<String>() {};
    Generic<String> anonymous2 = new GenericImpl<String>() {};
    Generic<String> concrete = new GenericImpl<String>();
    // assertion
    assertThat("Anonymous of abstract class", anonymous.getGenericType(), equalTo(String.class));
    assertThat("Anonymous of concrete subclass", anonymous2.getGenericType(), equalTo(String.class));
    assertThat("With non anonymous class it fails", concrete.getGenericType(), equalTo(String.class));
}
```

The third one is failing with `Expected: <class java.lang.String> but: was <class java.lang.Object>`

Now I'd like to use the Generic class with spring `@Autowired` annotation i.e.

```
@Autowired Generic<String> auto;

@Test
public void testAutowiring() {
    assertThat(auto, instanceOf(Generic.class));
    assertThat(auto.getGenericType(), equalTo(String.class));
}
```

but the second assertion fails with the same error as above (`Object` instead of `String`), because spring container internally instantiate it with `new GenericImpl<String>()`

I've already tried to make constructor of `GenericImpl<T>` protected and also to declare `GenericImpl<String>` itself abstract but in both cases spring fail with a Cannot instantiate bean exception.

Is there any simple way to tell spring to instantiate classes using anonymous classes?

### Additional details

The final class will convert a json stream into a POJO with Jackson and the Jackson library needs the `Class<T>` field to unmarshal objects.

```
// here I convert json stream to a POJO and I need the generic type
mapper.readValue(hit.source(), getGenericType());
```

Since I have multiple POJO classes to convert from to JSON I've implemented all the logic in a common class with generics called `Retriever`. At the end I'll have one Retriever for each POJO and often those retrievers are autowired in other classes.

```
@Autowired Retriever<Artifact> retriever;
```

Currently I've a constructor in `Retriever` which takes a `Class<T>` parameter and use it later to perform conversion. In the spring context I've this for autowiring

```
<!-- Since retriever has a Class<T> constructor this is the only way I found to resolve its dependency -->
<bean id="artifactRetriever" class="a.b.c.RetrieverImpl">
    <constructor-arg value="a.b.c.Artifact"/>
</bean>
```

and I need one of this for each POJO for which I need conversion. This approach works but it's a little verbose and it clutters the application context with useless lines. So I was looking for a way to get rid of all this noise in application context.

Comment: May I ask why do you need to get the type and how you intend to use it? If you decribe the actual problem perhaps someone can think of a different solution than messing with types

Comment: Are you using java `@Configuration` or XML context?

Comment: @c.s. I've added my use case.

Comment: @AndreyBalaguta currently I'm using XML and I'd prefer to keep it.

Comment: Don't think that being able to create and instantiate anonymous classes in-place with Spring will do much good removing this verbosity. Even with anonymous classes you have to pass the concrete type parameter, right? So why not pass it as a constructor argument.

Comment: Because if what I've asked is possible autowiring instances should be enough, i.e. `@Autowired Retriever<Artifact>` `@Autowired Retriever<OtherPojo>`. But maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, final solution for my use case will use the approach described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/503011/518204). It would be better because it will be possible to track usages and I'll get rid of every problem I'm having with the current approach.

In that way I can do the following

```
@Component
public class ArtifactImpl extends AbstractGenericImpl<Artifact> {
}

@Component
public class MaterialImpl extends AbstractGenericImpl<Material> {
}

@Component
class Usage {
  @Autowired ArtifactImpl foo;
  @Autowired MaterialImpl bar;
}
```

In this way everything is checked at compile time and I got rid of `Class<T>` constructor in fact I have autowiring in place (without @Qualifier) and the following test is working:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class AutowiringTest {
  @Autowired Usage test;

  public void testAutowiring() {
    assertThat(test.foo.getGenericType(), equalTo(Artifact.class));
    assertThat(test.bar.getGenericType(), equalTo(Material.class));
  }
}
```

#### Original answer

Ok, I've found out that what I'm asking will be useless because autowiring happens at runtime and so having two autowired object with different objects will lead to spring errors, i.e. this won't work:

```
@Configuration
class RetrieverProvider {
    @Bean 
    Retriever<Artifact> getArtifact() {
        return new RetrieverImpl<Artifact>() {};
    }

    @Bean 
    Retriever<Material> getMaterial() {
        return new RetrieverImpl<Material>() {};
    }
}

class InjectedAttempt {
    // at injection time, i.e. runtime, type erasure prevent spring to distinguish
    @Autowired Retriever<Artifact> foo; // this type
    @Autowired Retriever<Material> bar; // from this type
    // so it cannot perform injection by type
}
```

The only way to get that working is to use qualifiers in this way, but I don't like this approach, so I'll remain with xml configuration and constructor arguments.

```
@Configuration
class RetrieverProvider {

    @Bean @Qualifier("artifact") Retriever<Artifact> getArtifact() {
        return new RetrieverImpl<Artifact>() {};
    }

    @Bean @Qualifier("material")
    Retriever<Material> getMaterial() {
        return new RetrieverImpl<Material>() {};
    }


}

class Injected {

    @Autowired @Qualifier("artifact") Retriever<Artifact> foo;

    @Autowired @Qualifier("material") Retriever<Material> bar;
}
```

As a side note [guice has support for generic injections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4239638/518204), maybe spring has something similar.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to create and instantiate anonymous classes in-place with Spring, not with XML configuration (since it needs class name, and you don't have one).

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible with @Configuration classes? Or better will spring be able to distinguish `Retriever<Artifact>` from `Retriever<OtherClass>` without @Qualifier?