# Spring - autowiring generic implementation of generic interface

Tags: java, spring, generics, autowired

I've got small question. It's probably trivial, but I've never faced it before.

I have generic interface and a generic implementation of it. I wanted to autowire it, but an error occured. Here are the details:

***Interface***

```
@Service
public interface Serializing<T extends Serializable> {
    String serialize(T toBeSerialized);

    T deserialize(String toBeDeserialized, Class<T> resultType);
}
```

***Implementation***

```
@Service
public class JsonSerializer<T extends Serializable> implements Serializing<T> {
   /** code **/
}
```

***Autowire attempt***

```
private NoteDAO noteDAO;

@Qualifier("jsonSerializer")
private Serializing<UserComment> serializer;

@Autowired
public NoteController(NoteDAO noteDAO, Serializing<UserComment> serializer) {
    this.noteDAO = noteDAO;
    this.serializer = serializer;
}
```

***Error***

```
Parameter 1 of constructor in somepackagepath.NoteController required a bean of type 'anotherpackagepath.Serializing' that could not be found.
```

I want to keep it as simple as possible. I've check the web, but I've found only about defining my exact beans in configuration. I prefer to avoid it if possible.

Comment: what if you put the `@Qualifier` in the constructor?

Comment: It doesn't applicable to constructor. I also removed it, just to be sure (because there is only one implementation for now) and still not found anything.

Comment: What is the structure of your project? Is the component scanner able to find the bean?

Comment: @Peteef I meant on the `serializer` parameter -> `@Qualifier("jsonSerializer") Serializing<UserComment> serializer`

Comment: Yes it is able to find beans in the same package.

Answer (score 10):

In **your specific case**, Spring doesn't allow to use a generic type to be wired as dependency such as :

```
@Autowired
public NoteController(NoteDAO noteDAO, Serializing<UserComment> serializer) {
    this.noteDAO = noteDAO;
    this.serializer = serializer;
}
```

for a very simple reason : consistency.
This dependency that you made a Spring bean with `@Service` :

```
@Service
public class JsonSerializer<T extends Serializable> implements Serializing<T> {
   /** code **/
}
```

can be wired into other beans.

Imagine that the beans that depend on the `Serializing` instance don't use the same generic :
`Serializing<UserComment>` in `Foo` and `Serializing<UserQuestion>` in `Bar` such as :

```
public class Foo{

    @Autowired
    public Foo(NoteDAO noteDAO, Serializing<UserComment> serializer) {
        this.noteDAO = noteDAO;
        this.serializer = serializer;
    }

}
public class Bar{

    @Autowired
    public Bar(NoteDAO noteDAO, Serializing<UserQuestion> serializer) {
        this.noteDAO = noteDAO;
        this.serializer = serializer;
    }

}
```

Here the `Serializing` object is the same but each bean declares a distinct generic on.
So it would break the type safety of the generic type.

---

In fact, erasure of the generics is not the real problem there as [Spring (from Spring 4) owns a Resolver able to resolve the type](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-and-java-generics) :

> behind the scenes, the new ResolvableType class provides the logic of
>   actually working with generic types. You can use it yourself to easily
>   navigate and resolve type information. Most methods on ResolvableType
>   will themselves return a ResolvableType

And before Spring 4 you also had other workaround to accept generic types in the bean dependencies.
**The real problem is that you annotated a generic class with  `@Service` to make it a bean while it is an instance of this generic class that has to be configured as a bean.**

So to achieve what you want to do, declare the `JsonSerializer` beans that you want to instantiate in a `@Configuration` class :

```
@Configuration
public class SerializingBeans {

    @Bean
    public JsonSerializer<UserComment> userCommentSerializer() {
        return new JsonSerializer<UserComment>();
    }

    @Bean
    public JsonSerializer<UserAnswer> userAnswerSerializer() {
        return new JsonSerializer<UserAnswer>();
    }
}
```

You can now wire the dependency as a generic type :

```
@Service
public class NoteController {

    private Serializing<UserComment> userCommentSerializer;

    @Autowired
    public NoteController(Serializing<UserComment> serializer) {
        this.userCommentSerializer = serializer;

    }
}
```

Comment: Such a great answer! Thank you sir!

Answer (score 4):

It's related to java's type erasure : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

In java, you can'nt know the generic type at runtime.
The only workarround is to use anonymous classes or inherited classes with non-generic type : [Inject anonymous classes with spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922923/inject-anonymous-classes-with-spring)

Answer (score 2):

You have to tell Spring about all the beans you want it to autowire.  No exceptions.

If you cannot spell it out beforehand, then I'd say it's not a candidate for injection.

Somethings you need to have full control and call `new`.  Maybe your case is one of those.  There's nothing wrong with that; it just means that Spring DI isn't appropriate for that use case.

Comment: only work around is to create a subclass right? `class UserCommentSerializer extends JsonSerializer<UserComment> { ... }` and then inject that into the constructor

Comment: Maybe.  I'm not sure based on what has been posted.

Comment: As I said, I've never faced this kind of situation. I thought that Spring is able to recognize param type by specified interface. 

To be clear, I've got enabled component scanning.

Comment: Like they said above: type erasure is your problem.  I wonder why you're going to all this trouble when the Jackson JSON library will handle all this for you.  That's the standard for JSON serialization/deserialization in Spring Boot.

Comment: To be honest I'm using Jackson library inside. It's about flexibility to change serializing strategy easily.

Comment: You know your problem better than I do.  I can't help but think you're designing for a situation that is highly unlikely.  Once you annotate your classes properly Jackson will sort them out and you won't be changing them.  Do the simple thing.  YAGNI.

Comment: I'm glad.  Good luck.

Comment: @Lino It is an acceptable workaround before Spring 4. Declaring the beans with the generic types in a configuration classes is a more flexible way.