# Spring. Dynamic dependency injection

Tags: spring, generics, dependency-injection, spring-data

I have the following problem.

I have a generic class A

```
public class A<T, DAO extends JpaRepository<?, ?>>
{    

    @Autowired
    protected DAO daoObject;

    ......
```

and there I am trying inject a genreic DAO-object of the JpaRepository-type.

If I have only one implemetation of injected object(of JpaRepository), then there is no problem, but if I have more then one, then spring doesn't know which object it is to inject and throws an exception.

The question is: How can I dynamish based on generic information, inject the correct object?

Thank you.

```
public interface IRegisteredUserDAO extends JpaRepository<RegisteredUser, String> {

}


public interface IMailLogDao extends JpaRepository<MailLog, Long> {

   findByTo(String to);
}
```

and i used it so

```
public class RegisteredUserVM extends YBTableViewModel<RegisteredUser, IRegisteredUserDAO>
{
```

UPDATE:

```
public class MailLogVM extends YBTableViewModel<MailLog, IMailLogDao>
{    

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this using the latest Spring 4 RC1. Versions before that do not support generic injection at all. See [this ticket](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9965) and related commits for details.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Spring's `@Qualifier` annotation to inject the correct bean:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("IRegisteredUserDAOImpl")
protected DAO daoObject;
```

Here the bean with qualifier value "IRegisteredUserDAOImpl" is wired.

Comment: no, I can not.
I need dynamic there.
I corrects my question. see above

Comment: are you looking for something like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502994/spring-ioc-and-generic-interface-type