# Injection list of values into generic list through applicationcontext.xml?

Tags: java, spring, java-ee-7

I have below bean. I am using spring 3.x.

```
public class SomeClass<T extends OtherClass<K>, K> {

    List<T> listOfValues = new ArrayList<T>();

//some logic

}
```

How can i inject list of values into **listOfValues** through spring configuration file?

Thanks!

Comment: This answer comes from the source of Spring:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808914/spring-dynamic-dependency-injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [list](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-collection-elements) constant:

```
<bean id="SomeClassImpl" class="SomeClass" >
  <property name="listOfValues" >
    <util:list>
      <util:ref bean="bean1" />
      <util:ref bean="bean2" />
      ...
    </util:list>
  </property>
</bean>
```